# Characteristically simple subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. How can we show that $H$ is a characteristically simple subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Please see the last part of this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristically_simple_group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HInt: if $K \text{ char } H \trianglelefteq G $, then $K \trianglelefteq G$.